# Can not get last selected item in DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, null, selecteditem, selected, datagridviewcomboboxcell

my problem is like that: I have a C# application having datagridview which has some textboxes and comboboxes in its columns. All the columns get the data from a database. Textboxes are readonly. When i ask for values in each row, i get the last selected component's value (i.e. combobox' value because textboxes are readonly) as null.

For example:

I have 10 cells in a row. The comboboxes are at 7th, 8th and 9th indexes in a row, where indexes from 0 to 6 are texboxes. When i select 3 of them (in order of 7, 8, 9) i cannot get the cell value of 9.

`row.Cells[7].Value` is OK,
`row.Cells[8].Value` is OK, and
`row.Cells[9].Value` is `null`

When i select any two of them let say first 8 and then 7, i cannot get the cell value of 7.

`row.Cells[8].Value` is OK and
`row.Cells[7].Value` is `null`

When i select only one item let say 9, i got the cell value again null.

As a result i get the last selected DataGridViewComboBoxCell as null.

Can anyone help me in my problem please? Thanks for all your help.

Here is my code:

```
        private void cmbVariable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
            BringQuery(cmb.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

        private void BringQuery(string option)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = 10.2.6.14; Database = TTS; uid = myuser; password = mypassword");
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Track_Number, Parking_Area, Mission_Number, Track_Info, Time, Direction, Explanation from Traffic_Run_Table where Op_Type=@myType", conn);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from Traffic_Track_Table", conn);
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select * from Traffic_Driver order by Id_Number", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("myType", option));
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sda1.Fill(dt1);
                dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView2.Columns)
                {
                    col.DataPropertyName = col.Name;
                }
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbCol1, cmbCol2, cmbCol3;

            SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                cmbCol1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                cmbCol1.HeaderText = "Track 1";
                cmbCol1.Name = "Track1";
                cmbCol1.DataPropertyName = cmbCol1.Name;
                cmbCol1.ValueType = typeof(int);
                cmbCol1.Width = 50;


                cmbCol2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                cmbCol2.HeaderText = "Track 2";
                cmbCol2.Name = "Track2";
                cmbCol2.DataPropertyName = cmbCol2.Name;
                cmbCol2.ValueType = typeof(int);
                cmbCol2.Width = 50;

                sda2.Fill(dt2);
                dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Track";
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
                {
                    cmbCol1.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Track"]));
                    cmbCol2.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Track"]));
                }
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add(cmbCol1);
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add(cmbCol2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            SqlDataAdapter sda3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                cmbCol3 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                cmbCol3.HeaderText = "Driver";
                cmbCol3.Name = "Driver";
                cmbCol3.DataPropertyName = cmbCol3.Name;
                cmbCol3.ValueType = typeof(string);
                cmbCol3.Width = 260;

                sda3.Fill(dt3);
                dt3.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Id";
                dt3.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Driver";
                dt3.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Mission";
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt3.Rows)
                {
                    cmbCol3.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["Id"]).Trim() + " - " + Convert.ToString(dr["Dirver"]).Trim() + " - " + Convert.ToString(dr["Mission"]).Trim());
                }
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add(cmbCol3);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        public string CheckNull(object value, Type objType)
        {
            string retVal = string.Empty;

            if (value == null || value.ToString() == " " || value.ToString() == "")
            {
                if (objType == typeof(int))
                {
                    retVal = "0";
                }
                if (objType == typeof(string))
                {
                    retVal = "-";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = value.ToString();
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connForSave = new SqlConnection("Server = 10.2.6.14; Database = TTS; uid = myuser; password = mypassword");
            SqlCommand cmdForSave = new SqlCommand("insert into Traffic_Records values (@type, @trackNumber, @parkingArea, @missionNmb, @trackInfo, @time, @direction, @explanation, @track1, @track2, @driverId, @driverName, @driverMission, @date)", connForSave);
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataGridView2[7, row.Index].Selected = false;
                    dataGridView2[8, row.Index].Selected = false;
                    dataGridView2[9, row.Index].Selected = false;

                    connForSave.Open();
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("type", CheckNull(cmbVairable.SelectedItem.ToString(), typeof(string)));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("trackNumber", Convert.ToInt16(CheckNull(row.Cells[0].Value, typeof(int))));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("parkingArea", CheckNull(row.Cells[1].Value, typeof(string)));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("missionNmb", Convert.ToInt16(CheckNull(row.Cells[2].Value, typeof(int))));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("trackInfo", CheckNull(row.Cells[3].Value, typeof(string)));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("time", CheckNull(row.Cells[4].Value, typeof(string)));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("direction", CheckNull(row.Cells[5].Value, typeof(string)));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("explanation", CheckNull(row.Cells[6].Value, typeof(string)));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("track1", Convert.ToInt16(CheckNull(row.Cells[7].Value, typeof(int))));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("track2", Convert.ToInt16(CheckNull(row.Cells[8].Value, typeof(int))));

                    string[] sArray = null;

                    if (string.Compare(CheckNull(row.Cells[9].Value, typeof(string)), "0") != 0 && string.Compare(CheckNull(row.Cells[9].Value, typeof(string)), "-") != 0)
                    {
                        sArray = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString().Split('-');
                        sArray[0] = sArray[0].Remove(sArray[0].Length - 2, 1);
                        sArray[1] = sArray[1].Remove(0, 1);
                        sArray[1] = sArray[1].Remove(sArray[1].Length - 2, 1);
                        sArray[2] = sArray[2].Remove(0, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string temp = "0 - -";
                        sArray = temp.Split(' ');
                    }

                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("driverId", Convert.ToInt16(sArray[0]));
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("driverName", sArray[1]);
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("driverMission", sArray[2]);
                    cmdForSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", DateTime.Now);

                    cmdForSave.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmdForSave.Parameters.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n Line Number: " + ex.LineNumber());
                }
                connForSave.Close();
            } 
        }
```

Comment: can you post ur code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `DataGridView` does not commit user made changes instantly but only after row is validated (I think, may be wrong here). So after you selected last value and did not change row (so validate event has not fired) the value in combo box is still null.

To fix this add `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` (more info here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to your grid:

```
private void GridCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvAssignedProperties.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

and this why new values are committed right away.